# Testing if one group has bigger values than the other

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have one dimensional data that has been split into two groups. Now I would like to test wether the values in group one are 'bigger' than the values in group two. One naive way to do this would be to simply compare the averages. But I believe it doesn't really factor in the variation... What would be a good test to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot test whether the 'values' are larger in group 1 than group 2. I think what you would like to test is that the means are equal, i.e. $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ against $H_1: \mu_1 > \mu_2.$

Comment: If each group is is drawn from a normal population then you might want to consider an unpaired [Student's *t* test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test).  Otherwise the [Mann–Whitney *U* test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) may be worth reading about.  There are other possibilities